Unicode character giving unexpected result in Regex matchAll
I expect this code:
"I like to listen to Björk".matchAll(/\w+/gu)

To return
["I", "like", "to", "listen", "to", "Björk"]

However, what I actually get is
["I", "like", "to", "listen", "to", "Bj", "rk"]

Using the v flag is no different (and not supported in Node, it seems). Is this broken or am I doing it wrong? How do I make it work?

Well, JS regexen do support Unicode, but \w in particular only includes some ASCII characters…

/\p{L}+/gu seems to do a better job at matching unicode characters (Regex101 demo), although it will not match underscores and numbers as \w would

https://regex101.com/r/OE6EDe/1

Duplicate of: Unicode regex

In javascript regex a \w equals [a-zA-Z0-9_] no matter what flags you use.

Unicode-aware matching of word characters works when using \p{L}, instead of \w, which only matches ASCII, even in Unicode mode. More about \p{} can be found here.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/280712/383904
